# Inline Editable Grid - Fields Not Editable CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Inline editable grid is only working with default crm forms in crm 2013.The fields are editable.But if I create a custom view in subgrid it is not editable.
even the custom view in custom form is also not editable in the default form neither the default view is editable in custom form.Can anyone give solution?How to add a grid with editable fields in CRM forms

Answer (score 1):

Inline Editable Grids in CRM 2013 are limited in their scope to specific views set up for this.  You can't add new views that do this or do it on custom entities.  Other people have already asked about this:
https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/10b1898b-32dd-44a9-bb65-34ac190f344e/inline-editing-of-subgrid-in-opportunity-in-crm-2013?forum=crmdevelopment

If this doesn't cut it for you, look into 3rd party alternatives, there are plenty out there.  AbleBridge is probably the most visible solution (although I haven't tried their Inline grid solutions).
http://www.ablebridge.com/add-on-solutions/editable-crm-grid/